# Set raster properties in arcpy: Multiple no data values for single band raster

Tags: arcpy

I am using `SetRaster properties` with `arcpy` to quickly set the no data value of a raster.

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management("InputRaster", nodata = "1 0")
```

I also want to assign value `15` to nodata in my example, so that both values `0` and `15` are assigned no data. In the ArcGIS help for the tool (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/set-raster-properties.htm) I found the following

> If you want to define multiple NoData values for each band selection,
>   use a space delimiter between each NoData value within the
>   bands_for_nodata_value parameter.

I haven't found nodata = [[1, 0], [1, 15]] to be working. The reason why I would like to use `SetRasterProperties` is because it is way faster than for example `SetNull`. I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1.

Comment: have you tried nodata = [[1, 0 15]]... this based on:  _If you want to define multiple NoData values for each band selection, use a **space delimiter** between each NoData value within the bands_for_nodata_value parameter_ in the help files.

Comment: yes I tried, but this leaves me with a 'Syntax Error: Invalid syntax'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is lacking, but this works:

`arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management("InputRaster", nodata="1 0;1 15")`

Alternatively, you could use a [ValueTable](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/valuetable.htm) with two columns:

```
vt = arcpy.ValueTable(2)
vt.addRow('1 0')
vt.addRow('1 15')
arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management("InputRaster", nodata=vt)
```

That said, I don't know if either will give you the results you want. It won't actually change the values within the raster. I think you should use [Con](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm):

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('SPATIAL')

in_raster = 'InputRaster'
where = 'Value not in (0, 15)'
raster = arcpy.sa.Con(in_raster, in_raster, where_clause=where)
raster.save('OutputRaster')
```